# How can I download a compiled svelte file?

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite

I am trying to make a website which allows the user to click a button which downloads an HTML file. However, like the rest of my website, I want to write this file in Svelte. All the compiled CSS and JS should be in the single HTML file downloaded.

I am mainly struggling with compiling two svelte files (for the website and file) at once while keeping the CSS and JS in one file. I have tried using the `vite-plugin-singlefile` plugin; however, it only supports the compilation of one file.

Comment: Can you explain what that html file is supposed to be? Is it, itself, a svelte application? Because if so, you'd have to inline all the JS and CSS into that file, which would make it huge. It would make far more sense to just have folks download a .zip with the app in it instead (like a release).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, it's a svelte application. The downloaded file is only one page and there isn't much content on it so it shouldn't take too much storage.

Comment: Then just make it an API endpoint, where the link points to "yourserver.com/api/pages/download/somenamethatmakessense" that can bundle a single page on request (and then cache it). Or if it's a fixed (set of) page(s), have separate configs for each, and run each on its own as part of your startup so that the server can serve them as static content (but _not_ with the html mime-type. You want to send it as octet-stream, so that the browser doesn't try to load it as a webpage, but instead sees "pure data" and prompts the user to save it to disk)

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes), the `<a>` tag supports a `download` attribute that

> Causes the browser to treat the linked URL as a download

Therefore, you could write a button like so:

```html
<a href="/route-to-html" download>Download</a>
```

This will download the html file with its styling.

Comment: Why would it will download "with its styling"? It just downloads the one file pointed to by the URL, and nothing else.

Comment: You're right. OP seemed unsure about having css (and js) present in the downloaded html. I was simply trying to make clear that the solution I provided would download an html file containing the css as written by the OP in the .svelte file. I'm open to edits if you think I've written something misleading.

Comment: @Overasyco I've edited my initial question. I also want the JS to be present in the downloaded HTML file. Thanks for the help.